# What is the fastest data structures to sequentially insert/read/remove in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

I will be given around **100k coordinates** in a file. But the number of elements is **not fixed**. And I want to store them in a **Data Structure** that will be the **fastest to  insert/sequentially read/remove**. While the data-structure is iterated sequentially in a loop. 25% to 70% of the elements needs to be removed. Also, the order of the coordinates matters.

In such case, what will be the fastest data structures to insert/sequentially read/remove in C++?

Answer (score 6):

The answer largely depends on how you are *really* going to use your container.

Don't panic : use a `typedef` for `std::vector` to start with (or any other conatiner, it does not matter), and make your code generic on the container (as STL algorithms do):

```
typedef std::vector<Points> Coordinates
```

Once your program will be up and running (and you know how many add/remove etc... you are doing), **profile it**.

You will be free to change your container type (maybe to an `std::list<>` or `std::deque`) **only by changing this `typedef`**, and properly benchmark each container in real life scenarios.

At that point, you will *know* which container you need.

Answer (score 2):

`std::list` will provide the fastest SEQUENTIAL insertion, removal, and read.   You don't want to use a `std::vector` since it will have to re-allocate the entire array when you do insertions (unless you specify a pre-allocated buffer).

Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/.  As you can see, std::list is a doubly-linked list.  This will allow you to do insertions / removals at the head or tail of the list in constant time.  Iterating through the list in sequence is also (essentially) as fast as iterating through a vector.  What I mean by this is that both are constant time operations.  See the comments below about concerns regarding memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough info to really suggest a best fit here. How often do you insert & remove? But some food for thought:

If your coordinates are `trivially copyable` `std::vector` erase can actually be pretty fast with `memmove`. While iterating and you want to erase the current element, memmove over it and decrease your `i` or `iterator` ( it doesn't matter if it underflows for `size_t` as long as you do this last, as it will correctly overflow with the increment ). The same is possible with insert as long as you take care for re allocation, you should always `reserve` if `capacity() == size()`.

I'd advice against `std::list`, I'm hard pressed to ever find a case for it. If you want a double linked list behavior you can store `std::tuple< size_t, size_t, Coordinate >` and let the the first 2 elements signify the offset to the previous & next element. It would have way better cache behavior, but would still grow fragmented over time ( in which case you could periodically unfragment it if possible ). Another approach is to at least use a custom allocator for `std::list`, have a look at `boost::pool`.

Comment: Lets say, we will remove 50% to 70% of the elements.

Comment: First of all if you have 10k co-ordinates, and lets say for arguments sake that you will be inserting 10k more & erase 15k of that total, the actual traversal / erase / insert will still account for most likely tenths of a second on a somewhat modern machine. Do you need it to go faster or does this require real time? In any case I would try the vector proposed vector case, especially if it's not a one off run, since the performance of the vector won't deteriorate over time.

Comment: Currently, I'm handling 10k point and even 10 ms would count a lot. The algorithm could be O(n^2), so I need something faster.